# Cannot use GazeInput on HoloLens 2 since Unity Update to 2022.3.7f1 Subscribe

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk

Since I updated Unity from 2020.3 to 2022.3 I can't use GazeInput in the application anymore. Before the update, the application would ask for permission for Microphone, Camera and GazeInput. After the update I'm not asked for permission to use gaze anymore. There is also no option for gaze in the App settings:

[image]

I made sure that my "Package.appxmanifest" contains "gazeinput" as DeviceCapability (enabled in Unity Player Settings and Visual Studio)

I'm using MRTK 2.8.3 and VS22

Is thre a capability setting in OpenXR, MRTK or so, that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it: [image]

You need to add Eye Gaze Interaction Profile to OpenXR under XR Plugin Management.

Not sure why it's not enough to setup everything in the MRTK settings but it is what it is...